# Build Kernel in 16.04 - no firmware package built

Tags: 16.04, kernel, packaging

I've been successfully building a set of Linux kernels on 16.04 base for some time now. When I build the 4.14 kernel to make deb packages with:

```
make -j24 KDEB_PKGVERSION=1.custom deb-pkg
```

which has always produced the following 5 deb packages:

- linux-headers
- linux-image
- linux-image-4.x-dbg
- linux-libc-dev
- linux-firmware

I now only get these 4 deb packages:

- linux-headers
- linux-image
- linux-image-4.x-dbg
- linux-libc-dev

From 4.14 the linux-firmware package is no longer created. In 4.13 and prior, there was no issue.

Has there been any change in the way kernel packages are created in Ubuntu or is this a new Linux implementation?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem and could not solve it, but the main kernel image works as expected, so it is not an issue for me at the moment.

I thinks it is related to this change:

kbuild: deb-pkg: remove firmware package support
https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/cc18abbe449aafc013831a8e0440afc336ae1cba

Comment: Thanks for that. It looks like it is gone for good - https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/5620a0d1aacd554ebebcff373e31107bb1ef7769 for anyone who is interested int he reason.